# Google chrome graphical fixes for developers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am a web developer for a small company and we recently noticed a strange graphical issue with [our website](http://ecogrid.co.uk/) that only appears for users using Google chrome on windows 7 and 8.

The graphical issue occurs when our banner images fade in and fade out, all of the content below the navigation UI flashes white.

This issue is resolved if chrome is run in windows 8 mode though not if hardware acceleration is disabled.

Weirdly enough something else that fixes the bug is opening the developer tools window by inspecting an element, very unusual.

Is there any kind of fix I may have to add to the pages CSS similar to styling specifically for Internet Explorer?

Comment: Please give a link to where we can see it happening

Comment: if you click "our website" annd press the left and right arrow keys it should replicate the bug, alternatively here is a screen shot:

[image](http://ecogrid.co.uk/images/bug.png)

Comment: Can't think of an easy fix, but just to let you know that the same thing happens with Chrome (latest version) on Windows Vista.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I will have to just trawl through the code, I cant even identify the problem as of yet. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to move the following script include right down to the bottom of your page, right above the last `</body>` tag.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecogrid.co.uk/js/magentothem/bannersequence/jquery.sequence-min.js"></script>
```

It works for me, at least in the browser. I think the issue was related to the order of the code and perhaps the conflicting of jquery fade effects in the menu and the sequential slider.

*This is non related but... good practice. Whilst your at it you may want to move many other 'render blocking elements' down below the fold as well, this is better for load time optimization. But of course for more info see: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS*

Comment: Pretty much solved it! I think its the two sliders interacting causing a huge mess.